# Click function on widget Textview

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I want a use click function on widget text view. When I run it, I didn't meet any problem, but when I open the application, it always force closed.

Here is my code:

```
package com.adm.kana;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LyoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class H_Basic extends Fragment {
       TextView a;

       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View hiragana = inflater.inflate(R.Layout.h_basic, container, false);
              ((TextView)a.findViewById(R.id.H_a)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) { CallIntent(v); }
              });
       return hiragana;
              }

       public void CallIntent(View view){
              Intent ganti = null;
              switch(view.getId()){
                     case R.id.H_a:
                          ganti = new Intent(getActivity(),Play.class);
                          startActivity(ganti);
                          break;
              }
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output from logcat?

Comment: What error you seeing in Logcat?

Comment: i run it in my smartphone, so i didn't gain any error warning in my logcat

Comment: Did you try to set Logcat level to Verbose? it will show everything: warnings, errors, ... etc

Comment: how do i to set logcat level to verbose, because i never change anything in my Android Studio or Eclipse!

Comment: Check this sceenshot: http://prntscr.com/7hma0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
((TextView)a.findViewById(R.id.H_a)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) { CallIntent(v); }
              });
```

with this one:

```
((TextView)hiragana.findViewById(R.id.H_a)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View v) { CallIntent(v); }
              });
```

Its because you are calling on a null reference, so your `TextView` will never be found unless you use the rootView `hiragana`

Comment: If my answer does the trick, please accept it as the correct one, glad that I helped you out